# Problema agregando material desing a un proyecto angular existente

Tags: angular, material-design

No puedo usar ninguno de los modulos de angular material desing porque mi proyecto no lo reconoce.

constantemente me botá el error: 'mat-toolbar' is not a known element:

1. If 'mat-toolbar' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-toolbar' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

Esto me sucede para cualquier componente que intente utilizar.

Tengo material instalado
[![package.json][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/44msH.png

Cree un modulo llamado material.module.ts donde importo lo que necesito

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        MatToolbarModule,
    ],
    exports: [
        MatToolbarModule,
    ],
})
export class MaterialModule { }
```

en el app.module.ts estoy importanto el modulo MaterialModule

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import './vendor';
import { AidpassSharedModule } from 'app/shared/shared.module';
import { AidpassCoreModule } from 'app/core/core.module';
import { AidpassAppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AidpassHomeModule } from './home/home.module';
import { AidpassEntityModule } from './entities/entity.module';
// jhipster-needle-angular-add-module-import JHipster will add new module here
import { MainComponent } from './layouts/main/main.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './layouts/navbar/navbar.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './layouts/footer/footer.component';
import { PageRibbonComponent } from './layouts/profiles/page-ribbon.component';
import { ActiveMenuDirective } from './layouts/navbar/active-menu.directive';
import { ErrorComponent } from './layouts/error/error.component';
import { AboutUsComponent } from './home/about-us/about-us.component';
import { FeaturesComponent } from './home/features/features.component';
import { MaterialModule } from 'app/material.module.ts';



@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AidpassSharedModule,
    AidpassCoreModule,
    AidpassHomeModule,
    AidpassEntityModule,
    AidpassAppRoutingModule,
    MaterialModule,

    // jhipster-needle-angular-add-module JHipster will add new module here
  ],
  declarations: [MainComponent, NavbarComponent, ErrorComponent, PageRibbonComponent, ActiveMenuDirective, FooterComponent, AboutUsComponent, FeaturesComponent ],
  bootstrap: [MainComponent],
})
export class AidpassAppModule {}
```

Y un archivo html nuevo que solo tiene

```
<h1>
    XX
</h1>

<mat-toolbar>
    <span>My Application</span>
</mat-toolbar>
```

y el error no deja de aparecer:

```
ERROR in src/main/webapp/app/aidpass/patient/emergency-profile/emergency-profile.component.html:5:1 - error NG8001: 'mat-toolbar' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-toolbar' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-toolbar' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
```

Intento importar directamente el modulo de {MatToolbarModule} en app.module.ts y el error es el mismo